# Get the height of keyboard doesn't work on IOS 11 beta

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

I have the following code which worked on IOS 10, but now it doesn't work anymore when running on IOS 11 beta.

```
if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
    if let keyboardSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        print(keyboardSize)
    }
}
```

This is what I get when I print the size:

```
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 736.0, 414.0, 0.0)
```

Anyone knows why this has stopped working ? Or if I have any other alternatives to get the keyboard size ?

Comment: Same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569276/password-autofill-quicktype-bar-in-ios-11?

Comment: @MartinR: Yep , same issue here, with the same fix answer :)

Answer (score 15):

Use `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` instead of `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`

So changing your code to the following will fix your issue:

```
if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
    if let keyboardSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        print(keyboardSize)
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the correct answer, and should be marked as such

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue. 
The answer of Doug Amos is right. I just want to make it clearer. 
Here is my code:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification){

        var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
        var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        if keyboardFrame.size.height <= 0 { // to fix bug on iOS 11
            keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        }
        keyboardFrame = self.view.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code in my app with **Swif 3+**

```
    var userInfo = notification.userInfo
    if let keyboardFrame = (userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue{
        print(keyboardFrame.height)
        if keyboardFrame.size.height <= 0 { // To fix bug on iOS 11
            if let newKeyboardFrame = (userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue{
                print(newKeyboardFrame.height)
            }
        }
    }
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
```