# ScrollView's scrollRectToVisible on keyboard notifications Not working properly in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios11

I have a scroll view with many text fields as subviews, I wanted the selected text field(_activeField) to scroll up when keyboard appears.

```
- (void) keyboardUP:(NSNotification *)notification
{
NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height + 10, 0.0);
_scroller.contentInset = contentInsets;
_scroller.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

CGRect aRect = App_Delegate.window.frame;
aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;

CGRect rect = [_activeField convertRect:_activeField.frame fromView:App_Delegate.window];

if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, rect.origin) )
{
    [_scroller scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:YES];
}
```

}

This code is working fine for iOS 10, but in iOS 11 , its not working ,"scrollRectToVisible" doesn't scroll  the ScrollView even if its content size is correct.

Comment: Try using [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) instead, much much easier

Comment: I am basically curious to know if there is any particular change in ScrollView in iOS11 which is restricting the function of this code.

Comment: I had the same issue, didn’t have time to check, because production app was having the issue, so I added the library and it was fixed

Comment: I’m just curious now, is Safe Area part in the latest Xcode causing this?

Comment: I found a workaround using UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey to get keyboard height instead of using UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey, but this still is just a temporary solution , it still doesnt help in some other further beta version of iOS 11.Still no clue whats causing this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about

```
- (void) keyboardUP:(NSNotification *)notification
```

but have seen a similar problem with

```
- (void)handleKeyobardDidShowNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
```

It looks like this no longer runs on the main thread in iOS 11.

Try running you call to scrollRectToVisible on the main thread as follows

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_scroller scrollRectToVisible:targetPosition animated:YES];
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a duplicate of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46384282).

use the `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`

```
if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
    if let keyboardSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        print(keyboardSize)
    }
}
```

and for ObjC

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
}
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the issue you linked. And your answer does not solve the problem.

Comment: Vin Gazoil, I have a project with the OPs exact issue that stopped working with iOS11. This was the solution, and it had been discussed before. Instead of pushing your opinion, why don't you show me exactly what you're talking about because I don't think your comment is appropriate in any sense or manner of the word.

Comment: In the issue you linked, the OP had trouble getting the height of the keyboard, here the OP has trouble with the scrollRectToVisible function. The code you provided may solve your issue, it didn't solved mine (same as OP's), but IMHO it's a poor solution as the real problem is, as mentioned by Peter, a problem with the function not being called on the main thread. Sorry if my first comment was kind of rude.

Comment: Vin, in . my approach and as any approach as I can recall, for iOS programming you have to find manually handle the screen offset issue due to keyboard's show firstResponder .. the offset is calculated by the height of the keyboard .. here, the OP's `CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
` wasn't working, and the fix was to listen to the updated notification  .. if you have a better solution provide it instead of raising claims that can't be backed .. mine was for production code, and this wasn't an experiment when it was noted to work